# How ASP.NET MVC SignInManager works?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have written a code which is similar to automatically generated by using Individual User Account authentication mode in ASP.NET MVC. When I run it, I don't get any exceptions but when I then check this.User, the name property is null, not "Test". When I run automatically generated code, the name is always  changed. Why my code does not change this.User?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var dbContext = new IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>("DefaultConnection");
    dbContext.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

    var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(dbContext);
    var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser, string>(userStore);
    var result = userManager.Create(new IdentityUser { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), UserName = "Test" });

    var signInManager = new SignInManager<IdentityUser, string>
         (userManager, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);

    var toSign = userManager.FindByName("Test");
    signInManager.SignIn(toSign, true, true);

    return View();
}
```

Comment: At which line should your code change this.User?

Comment: signInManager.SignIn(toSign, true, true);

Comment: How is signInManager implemented? How are your triggers implemented?

Comment: It is default ASP.NET Identity signInManager